# Getting random 404 errors in IIS PHP site

Tags: php, html, iis, iis-8

On the site I have a very strange situation. When I refresh the site (a couple of times), most of the times I get 404 errors on random files, mostly images. The 404 errors are returned by IIS I think. I don't know why. The files with 404 errors are there and directly opening by url does actually work.

You can easy reproduce to hit the refresh button on your browser and checking out the console. You will see the 404 errors like this randomly appearing.

**What I have tried so far, unsuccesful**

- Made sure the group `IIS_IUSRS` have read rights on all resources
- Have enabled `static content compression` in IIS
- Disabling `static content compression` has a positive effect, the 404 errors are less common but still occur.
- Moving images to another directory

**My question**

What could cause this behaviour and what can I try to do to solve this problem? I have spend many hours to figure it out myself so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm very sure the error is coming from IIS. I use nginx and had once encountered same error which I was able to resolve by making some changes in nginx sites available config file and ensuring that images are treated as images

Comment: I agree. Could it be caused because of my web.config configuration (and url rewrite)? I will try if I can see it the images are treated as images.

Comment: I don't really have a good answer as I'm not used to IIS, but try URL rewrite and could be the case here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [VPS provider](http://www.supcloud.nl) was so kind to support me with this problem. The cause of these problems is the [dynamic ip restrictions](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions) settings in IIS8. I had the restrictive setting active for max 20 requests per ip from withing 200ms. I believe this is the default setting in IIS now.